# Sort by multiple criteria excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Simple spreadsheet, would like to sort by two criteria.  My code works when I specify cells, i.e., A2:A21, but not when I substitute variable name, i.e., "Prioritycolumn".  This code moves priority rows to the top, but doesn't sort by value.  Sorts by OMColumn properly.  EDIT:  Even when I remove the second sort, returns all priority rows at the top, but not in ascending order.

```
Application.Goto Reference:="ListArea"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PARTS ORDER LIST").Sort.SortFields.Clear

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PARTS ORDER LIST").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range _
    (PriorityColumn), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PARTS ORDER LIST").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range _
    (OMColumn), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
    
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PARTS ORDER LIST").Sort
    .SetRange Range(AllColumn)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `PriorityColumn` and `OMColumn`?

Comment: Should this not be `Sortfields.Add` rather than `.Add2`?  The latter should deprioritize your sort as the second highest priority to the initial sort., so your second `.Add2` is essentially negligible.

Comment: @BigBen, PriorityColumn is "A2:A21"  OMColumn is "D2:D21".

Answer (score 0):

Following up my comment, I believe this would give you a better result:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PARTS ORDER LIST")
    .Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(21,lastCol)).Sort Key1:=.Range(.Cells(1,PriorityColumn),.Cells(21,PriorityColumn)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal, Header:=xlyes
    .Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(21,lastCol)).Sort Key1:=.Range(.Cells(1,OMColumn),.Cells(21,OMColumn)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal, Header:=xlyes
End With
```

This sort `PriorityColumn` first (lowest priority), followed by sorting `OMColumn` (highest priority).

Note that `lastCol` is used as I don't know the last column in your total range.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error.  There were some numbers entered as text.  Code works as originally printed.  Thanks for your help!